# Upgrading to Android Studio 1 broke Roboelectric tests

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, automated-tests, robolectric

I have a bunch of Roboelectric tests which ran without a problem on Android Studio 0.8.9. However, when I upgraded to Android Studio 1 today, many of Roboelectric tests are failing. This is not necessarily an Android Studio issue and I believe it is more related to gradle, since when I run "./gradlew clean test", the tests still fail.

Here are the lines I changed in my build.gradle:

1- Removed applicationId from defaultConfig

2- Replaced runProguard WITH minifyEnabled

3- Replaced classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+' WITH classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

4- Replaced classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.11.+' WITH classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.14.+'

The errors are somewhat similar. This is one for instance:

ImageUtilTest.java:31: Robolectric.buildActivity(AboutActivity.class).create().start().get();

Error: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException at ImageUtilTest.java:31

So, I am not sure what the issue is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And `ImageUtilTest` does what at line 31?

Comment: Robolectric.buildActivity(AboutActivity.class).create().start().get();

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the values defined in @Config needed some changes. So, after updating the values for both "manifest" and "resourceDir" in @Config for each test, they all passed without a problem.